# XAML Code IsChecked Trigger On ToggleButton

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

For some reason the following code will not work

```
<ToggleButton Content="Options" x:Name="Options" Height="{Binding ElementName=Connect,Path=ActualHeight}">
    <ToggleButton.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="OptionsPanel" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ToggleButton.Triggers>
</ToggleButton>
<StackPanel x:Name="OptionPanel">

</StackPanel>
```

the error I am getting is

> Error 1   The member "IsChecked" is not recognized or is not
>   accessible.

Could someone please assist in what I screwed up?
My brain has turned to Swiss cheese and I cant see it

Comment: Have you tried `Property="OptionPanel.IsChecked"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use `ToggleButton.Triggers`, nor can you because there is no `OptionsPanel` in the `ControlTemplate`.  Additionally, you'd want to use `Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked"`, but it still wouldn't work out for you.  Since you are using `x:Name`, you can simply do this:

```
<Page x:Class="WPF.MainWindow"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      Title="MainWindow"
      Height="350"
      Width="525">
    <Page.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="B2VisibilityConverter" />
    </Page.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ToggleButton Content="Options"
                      x:Name="Options" />
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1"
                    Visibility="{Binding ElementName=Options, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource B2VisibilityConverter}}">
            <Button>Button 1</Button>
            <Button>Button 2</Button>
            <Button>Button 3</Button>
            <Button>Button 4</Button>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Clicking the `ToggleButton` will show/collapse the StackPanel and it's contents just the way you want.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I don't know why I was trying to think of this in the most complicated way possible. Waaaaay to much coding was had yesterday