# The member “IsChecked” is not recognized or is not accessible

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, .net-core-3.1

I am creating WPF Desktop application in Visual studio 2019 with **.NetCore 3.1**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}"
       x:Key="toggle">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
                   Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="Beige" />
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
                   Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="Brown" />
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>

<Grid>
    <ToggleButton Style="{DynamicResource toggle}" Width="150" Height="150" Background="Aquamarine"/>
</Grid>
```

So it show the message

> The member `IsChecked` is not recognized or is not accessible.

Anybody have any idea what I might be doing wrong with this piece of my code. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XAML Code IsChecked Trigger On ToggleButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25508479/xaml-code-ischecked-trigger-on-togglebutton)

Comment: Should add the `TargetType` to the `ControlTemplate`: `<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}"></ControlTemplate>`.

Comment: Why just don't use a `Style.Triggers` instead of overriding a control template? Default control template for togglebutton and button base doesn't contain IsChecked property

Comment: I tried it, but it removed the error but it also hided my ToggleButton and not showing it.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Style.Trigger seems to be not containing background color field as property.

Comment: @HamzaJawed Please, have a look at my answer, I've added a complete control template

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski thanks your answer helped me alot. It worked fine. Please tell me why is it necessary to add border and content presentator to make it work?

Comment: It's wpf basics, every content control should have a content presenter to show the content somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jawed,
You can try with the below code:

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType ="{x:Type ToggleButton}" x:Key="toggle">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">  
                        <Border CornerRadius="3" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter Margin="3" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
               VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>                      
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <SolidColorBrush>                                            <SolidColorBrush.Color>Beige</SolidColorBrush.Color>
                                        </SolidColorBrush>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Background">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <SolidColorBrush>
                                            <SolidColorBrush.Color>Brown</SolidColorBrush.Color>
                                        </SolidColorBrush>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>            
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ToggleButton Style="{DynamicResource toggle}" Width="150" Height="150"/>
    </Grid>
```

Thanks,

Comment: I tried this piece but it hides my ToggleButton and dont show in Design mode and runtime.

Comment: code updated. @HamzaJawed please check it again. thanks

Comment: Thanks. It worked like a charm. But one question why is  (<Border CornerRadius="3" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter Margin="3" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
               VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>) this thing necessary.

Comment: If we want to use background of an element we need to add border first.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.border?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else, the property IsChecked is not accessible because the ControlTemplate does not have any TargetType.

What worked for me was -

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType={x:Type ToggleButton}>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        ...
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```